# How can I set the default position of a trackbar in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

In OpenCV, using the createTrackbar function, how can someone set the default slider position to a maximum?

I have several sliders, some representing minimum values, and some representing maximum values. It would be nice, if the sliders for a max value, started out at the maximum (255), rather than the minimum (0).

I have looked around on the [OpenCV documentation pages](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html), but I have not located a solution.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

# Create a black image, a window
#img = np.zeros((300,512,3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.namedWindow('hsv')
cv2.namedWindow('masq')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# create trackbars for color change
cv2.createTrackbar('R-low','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('R-high','image',0,255,nothing)

cv2.createTrackbar('G-low','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('G-high','image',0,255,nothing)

cv2.createTrackbar('B-low','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('B-high','image',0,255,nothing)


while(1):
    ret, img = cap.read()
    # Convert BGR to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

    # get current positions of four trackbars
    rl = cv2.getTrackbarPos('R-low','image')
    rh = cv2.getTrackbarPos('R-high','image')

    gl = cv2.getTrackbarPos('G-low','image')
    gh = cv2.getTrackbarPos('G-high','image')

    bl = cv2.getTrackbarPos('B-low','image')
    bh = cv2.getTrackbarPos('B-high','image')

    lower = np.array([rl,gl,bl])
    upper = np.array([rh,gh,bh])

    print(rl)

    img[:] = [bl,gl,rl]

    # Threshold the HSV image to get only certain colors
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)    


    res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask)

    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    cv2.imshow('masq',mask)
    cv2.imshow('hsv',hsv)


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

On load, it ends up looking like this:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the value field:

> Python: cv.CreateTrackbar(trackbarName, windowName, value, count,
> onChange) → None
>
> Parameters:
> trackbarname – Name of the created trackbar.
>
> winname – Name of the window that will be used as a parent
> of the created trackbar.
>
> value – Optional pointer to an integer
> variable whose value reflects the position of the slider. Upon
> creation, the slider position is defined by this variable.
>
> count –
> Maximal position of the slider. The minimal position is always 0.
>
> onChange – Pointer to the function to be called every time the slider
> changes position.
>
> This function should be prototyped as void
> Foo(int,void*); , where the first parameter is the trackbar position
> and the second parameter is the user data (see the next parameter). If
> the callback is the NULL pointer, no callbacks are called, but only
> value is updated. userdata – User data that is passed as is to the
> callback. It can be used to handle trackbar events without using
> global variables.

[Source](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't pay much attention reading documentation, there you can find:
**value** – Optional pointer to an integer variable whose value reflects the position of the slider. Upon creation, the slider position is defined by this variable.
**count** – Maximal position of the slider. The minimal position is always 0.

As i can understand this, you need just to set a `value` to the same like a `count`

Comment: or I interpreted it differently. oh well, I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

The value should be in integers usually 0 - 100 scale, if the default value is betweek 0 - 1 just multiply x 100.

that worked for me.